# Sharing variable across all vue component instances

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-mixin

I am trying to refactor some code and move some code to the mixin. But I am getting different behaviour. I wanted an object to be shared across all instances of a component. So I had written something like below

```
<script>
export default {
  registryManager: new RegistryManager()
}
</script>
```

In the instances, I was accessing this by `this.$options.registeryManager`. 
Now I have moved this code to a mixin.

Mixin

```
export default {
  registryManager: new RegistryManager()
}
```

Component

```
<script>
import registryManager from './mixins/registryManager';
export default {
  mixins: [registryManager]
}
</script>
```

Let say you are having 2 components A, B. Earlier, All the instances of component A had one registryManager and All the instances of component B had one separate registryManger. 
With the use of mixin, All the instances of component A and component B are sharing one registry manager because regardless of how many components are using a mixin, only one instance of the mixin is created
Is there any way to create one instance of the mixin per component to get earlier behaviour?

Comment: A new instance is created for every component that you import the `mixin` into.
So not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Not sure if that is the case. All the component are getting same instance of the registry manager.

Comment: Is there any cleaner way of sharing a variable amongst all instances of a component?

Comment: Yes, use a state management library like `Vuex`.
If a mixin is written correctly, they behave like `pure` functions. Not sure If I understand your issue.

Comment: Is there a reason why it was defined as an option? Is it supposed to be overridden somewhere?

Comment: Registry Manager is a store which contains information related to the dynamically generated styles of a component which can be used in other instances. So if there are styles which are already generated I need not to re-generate styles for the same component. 
For more details refer
https://github.com/shivgarg5676/vue-jss/blob/feature/component-level-reusability/components/with-styles.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. There is only one class instance, `new RegistryManager()` is evaluated only once in mixin module, Vue is unaware that `registryManager` needs to be instantiated multiple times.

Since there is a one-to-one relationship between component constructor and class instance, it can be assigned as constructor property.

This can be done globally:

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, 'registryManager', {
  get() {
    if (!this.constructor._registryManager) {
      this.constructor._registryManager = new RegistryManager();
    }

    return this.constructor._registryManager;
  }
});
```

The class is also lazily instantiated this way. Can be placed inside `install(Vue) {...}` and used as a plugin.

Or locally as a mixin:

```
  beforeCreate() {
    if (!this.constructor._registryManager) {
      this.constructor._registryManager = new RegistryManager();
    }

    this.registryManager = this.constructor._registryManager;
  }
```

Comment: This way It will be added to all the components. Isn't there a way to inject it in the components which include the mixin? I will try this piece once and try to do some modifications for the desired behaviour.

Comment: It may be not a bad thing to do this globally. But yes, it can be a mixin too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a factory method inside the mixin that expects an id (name of the component for instance) and returns an instance of a `RegisterManager`.

The mixin module will have to keep a map from ids to instances of `RegisterManager`.

Something similar to this.

```
const instances = {
}

export default {
  getRegistryManager: (id) => {
    if (!instances[id]) {
      instances[id] = new RegistryManager()
    }

    return instances[id]
  }
}
```

And then call `getRegistryManager` from your components.

```
<script>
  import getRegistryManager from './mixins/registryManager';
  export default {
   mixins: [getRegistryManager("ComponentName")]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That is a nice solution any day. But the problem is that I am writing a node module to be used by others. First, I can't ask them to do a lot of things. The user should not be bothered to create a registry. Secondly, a lot of users do not provide names or ids may clash.